# QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON

Tags: oracle-10g, hql, jpa, seam

Cuando corro una consulta con  el entity manager

```
entityMan.createQuery(str.toString()).getResultList().size();
```

Me arroja un error de sintaxis

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, 
column 534 [select catfiguras.FIGURA_OPERATIVA_ID  
,catfiguras.GRUPO_FIGURA_ID  ,catfiguras.PERMITE_BRIGADA 
,catfiguras.BTCR_FIGURA_OPERATIVA ,catfiguras.CALCULO_RECURSOS_HUMANOS
,catfiguras.EJERCICIO_ID  ,catfiguras.FIGURA_OPERATIVA_PADRE_ID 
,catfiguras.TIPO_FIGURA_OPERATIVA_ID ,catfiguras.AUDITORIA_SESION_ID 
,catfiguras.DESCRIPCION  ,catfiguras.ESTATUS  
,catfiguras.FIGURA_ANTEPROYECTO  ,catfiguras.GRUPO_PUBLICACION_ID 
,catfiguras.NOMBRE  ,catfiguras.USADMS  from CAT_FIGURAS_OPERATIVAS 
catfiguras  join DIME_CONTROL_CALCULO_FIGURAS dmcc ON  
dmcc.figura_operativa_id=catfiguras.FIGURA_OPERATIVA_ID where 1=1  and 
catfiguras.CALCULO_RECURSOS_HUMANOS=1  and 
catfiguras.FIGURA_ANTEPROYECTO=0  and catfiguras.ESTATUS=1  and 
catfiguras.TIPO_FIGURA_OPERATIVA_ID=1  AND catfiguras.EJERCICIO_ID=1 order
  by catfiguras.FIGURA_OPERATIVA_ID]
```

Pero el correr exactamente la misma consulta en mi base de datos `Oracle` se ejecuta sin problemas. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo solventar este problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya lo pude resolver, primero le puse la palabra `WITH` de HQL y así me dió un error más específico, que la entidad no está mapeada, es decir no estaba corriendo HQL sino SQL de Oracle.

Se corrige cambiando el código a:

```
entityMan.createNativeQuery(str.toString()).getResultList().size();
```